# Re render FieldControl react reactive forms

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I'm using React Reactive Forms, i have two componentes my "SelectInput" component and my parent component with a FieldControl from React Reactive Forms.
I call an API to get all the clients from the backend and stored them using useState hook, and when the promise end i want to pass this clients to my SelectInput but it just renders one time, so the first time it render clients is equal to [] that's before calling the API

Is there anyway make this work?

This is where i call the SelectInput and pass what is inside of "clients"

```
<FieldControl
    name="client"
    render={props => <SelectInput {...props} />}
    meta={{
    label: 'Client',
    options: clients
    }}
/>
```

This is my SelectInput component

```
import React from 'react';
const SelectInput = ({ handler, touched, hasError, meta }) => {
    return (
        <div key={meta} className="ml-2 mt-2 w-full self-auto">
            <p className="text-gray-700 text-lg">{meta.label}</p>
            <select
                className={`flex-grow form-control outline-none ${
                    (touched && hasError('required')) || hasError('notExist') ? 'error' : ''
                }`}
                {...handler()}
            >
                <option value="Default">Select one option</option>
                {meta.options.map(option => {
                    return (
                        <option key={option.value} value={option.value}>
                            {option.label}
                        </option>
                    );
                })}
            </select>
            <div>
                {touched && hasError('required') ? (
                    <p className="text-red-700 text-xs">Field {meta.label} is required</p>
                ) : null}
            </div>
        </div>
    );
};

export default SelectInput;
```

Comment: Were you able to solve this?

Answer (score 0):

Passing `strict={false}` to `FieldControl` could help.